# Distance between a distribution and an empirical distribution of samples

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimal-transport

Looking for a reference on what I think is a standard result.

For a measure $\mu \in P(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $y_1, \dots, y_N \sim \mu$ be independent samples.

The empirical distribution associated with the samples is the discrete measure
$$ \hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{Y_i} \,.$$

Can we bound the Wasserstein distance $W_2(\mu,\hat{\mu})$?

I heard somewhere that it is of order $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ with high probability, but I can't find a reference.

Comment: [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397615)?

Comment: @user10354138 great, thanks. Looks like theorem 1 says the distance is $O(1/\sqrt{N})$.